# link_to/ button_to to call function without changing view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
#my_page.html.erb

<%= form_tag save_text_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :test_input, @text %>
  <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>

# in your controller

def my_page
  @text= File.open('your_file.txt').read
end

def save_text
  updated_text = params[:test_input]
  # do something with the text
end

# in your routes.rb
post "save_text" => "your_controller_name#save_text", as: "save_text
```

I have this code, whenever I click submit, it change to view of localhost:3000/save_text. How can I update text without changing view

Comment: No, I mean use JavaScript to call your `save_text` method. That way you won't leave your view. If you don't mind the page "refreshing" Then at the end of your `save_text` method, use `render` to render the view you want to see.

Comment: Ok, I understood, tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `remote: true` with rails UJS module (built in by default), like so

```
<%= form_tag save_text_path, remote: true do %>
  ...stuff
<% end %>
```

That will submit your form to the server via AJAX, and then on the server you would normally generate a piece of javascript to manipulate your page, like update content, show flashes, etc.

```
def save_text
  ...
  render js: "alert('Hello');"
end
```

Comment: In reder js: "#wall of code"

Is there anyway such as

render js: "mypage.js.erb"

and #mypage.js.erb 
alert('');

Comment: sure, you can just create the `save_text.js.erb` file in your views and skip the explicit `render` call in your action. rails should automatically pick your `.js.erb` file and render whatever you put in there. that's actually how it supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

You could do either of the following:

```
def save_text
  updated_text = params[:test_input]
  # do something with the text
  # you have to pass in the @text instance var below. Pass in the text you want to
  # display to that instance var
  @text= updated_text
  flash[:notice] = "Text saved"
  render :my_page
end

#OR

def save_text
  text = Text.create(params[:text_input]) #assumes params[:text_input] is a hash of text attributes
  redirect_to my_page_path(text_id: text.id), notice: "Text saved"
end

def my_page
  @text = Text.find(params[:text_id])
end
```

Both options will lead to page refreshes but will display the same page. The redirect approach will lead you back to the my_page url while the render approach will render the my_page template but will have the save_text url. You could also use the AJAX route, but it will be a bit more involved.

Comment: I don't want to refresh page so I think Ajax is better.

Comment: I used redirect_to but it don't update text in text_field_tag. Using render can update text but I don't want to change my url, how can I fix that error

Comment: You decided to not use AJAX? If you don't want to change the url, then use the redirect_to approach. You could pass in params to the my_page_path so you could access the text. Will update my answer with how you can do it.